# Import TMX maps in MonoGame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, tmx

I would appreciate if someone could tell me the steps to load the TMX map in Monogame for Windows Phone 8 or provide me with some tutorials to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try use any tmx-library loader for XNA. As example [this](http://windowsphonedevelopments.com/tmx-map-loader-xna-1-0). Transfer of the project from xna on monogame shouldn't present difficulties. Few words about porting [here](http://www.wpcentral.com/xna-dead-long-live-xna)

Answer (score 2):

Any of the open source XNA / .NET map loaders should be able to be used with MonoGame. There's a list on the [Tiled github page](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/Support-for-TMX-maps#microsoft-xnanet).

You'll need to recompile the map loader by replacing the XNA references with MonoGame equivalents. I did a similar thing with the [tIDE map editor](https://tide.codeplex.com/) when I created [Rock Run](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.craftworkgames.rockrun).

I haven't used Tiled in a game but I did build a prototype once with the [TiledMax](http://tiledmax.xpod.be/) loader.